# full calendar js wont render, shows only header buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

im using this [event calendar plugin](http://fullcalendar.io/download/) but no calendar is rendered except its header button and only a calendar is shown when I click on any of those header button (refer below image)

[image]

as you can see on my console, everything has been set correctly (linking script and stylesheet).

declaration of scripts at the bottom part of the html (just to make sure the dom is loaded before the script calls)

```
<!-- full calendar -->
<script type="application/javascript" src="/core/plugins/fullcalendar/moment.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="/core/plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
```

and its stylesheet at the top of the html page (inside the  tag)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/core/plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css" />
```

and then call it

```
//calendar
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        defaultDate: '2015-02-12',
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events: [
            {
                title: 'All Day Event',
                start: '2015-02-01'
            },
            {
                title: 'Long Event',
                start: '2015-02-07',
                end: '2015-02-10'
            },
            {
                id: 999,
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                start: '2015-02-09T16:00:00'
            },
            {
                id: 999,
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                start: '2015-02-16T16:00:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Conference',
                start: '2015-02-11',
                end: '2015-02-13'
            },
            {
                title: 'Meeting',
                start: '2015-02-12T10:30:00',
                end: '2015-02-12T12:30:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Lunch',
                start: '2015-02-12T12:00:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Meeting',
                start: '2015-02-12T14:30:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Happy Hour',
                start: '2015-02-12T17:30:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Dinner',
                start: '2015-02-12T20:00:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Birthday Party',
                start: '2015-02-13T07:00:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Click for Google',
                url: 'http://google.com/',
                start: '2015-02-28'
            }
        ]

});
```

but if i resize the window, it shows. any ideas, clues, help, suggestions, recommendation is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Have you included `jquery.js`? Just inspect element and check whether DOM has loaded your calendar or not?

Comment: i think the json you are using is not proper have it check at jsonlint...for your consideration i am attaching the modified json in the answer.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao: yes i have been include the jquery and moment js correctly as it shows no error in my console.

Comment: @Abhishek: I tried your json codes but sadly, it still not working

Comment: @GuruprasadRao: i did inspect the element but all i see is the calendar header elements (header button as what you see in the picture) like the calendar (showing dates stuffs) is not loaded there or not rendered in.

Comment: Ok.. Can you just put the calendar part in whole new `div` like my suggestion is let it come down and take whole space in the page!

Comment: @GuruprasadRao: i did make it full page, sadly it still not showing.

Comment: Did you copy the exact same code what was there in example of the site?

Comment: yes of course. and I made it working unto my other site.

Comment: maybe i should try different plugin, any suggestion and recommendation please?

Comment: but if i resize the window, it shows, any ideas?

Comment: thank you, it is fixed now, there some sort of hide and show stuff going on in my html.

Comment: what was your solution then ?

Comment: @AureleCollinet it wont render because it was hidden in css then using document ready then show that part will document loaded, calendar is there but the height is 0 so i need to give it height and then it shows

Answer (score 1):

You might have two problems, either you're missing a defaultView or you need to run 'render' function from fullCalendar object. Try loading the calendar in its simplest way to make sure you have everything working (correct libraries etc), something like:

```
calendar.fullCalendar({
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        editable:false,
        allDaySlot:false,
        timezone: 'local',
        maxTime: "24:00:00"
    })
```

If this works but it isn't rendering the calendar then try running this function AFTER calendar being initated. This will force the calendar to be rendered again..

```
calendar.fullCalendar('render')
```

Another issue you might be experiencing is that at the rendenring stage of the page the Calendar DOM is hidden ( display:none or calendar.hide() ) then on this case make sure to run the last function after the calendar is being show. Common libraries like bootstrap have tab classes, this is a very common bug. To make sure to render the calendar AFTER a tab is active, do this

```
 $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {

    var tab = e.currentTarget.hash

    if( tab == '#tab'){

        calendar.fullCalendar('render')

    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

- Add jquery. From [documentation](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/usage/)

> jQuery and Moment must be loaded before FullCalendar's JavaScript.

- Make the call to fullCalendar when jquery is ready. From the same page of documentation

  ```
  $(document).ready(function() {    
      // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

      $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
          // put your options and callbacks here
      })
  });
  ```

I did a [plunker with your code](http://plnkr.co/edit/7TVQD3?p=preview) where you can check it.

Comment: I have been added the jquery on the header part of my html and moment js on the bottom part of my html (no errors in the console as you can see). Please assume that it is already declared in this issue.

Comment: Look into your html elements if fullcalendar render a div `<div class="fc-view-container"` and check it style. Is it there but hidden?

Comment: thank you, it is fixed now, there some sort of hide and show stuff going on in my html.

Answer (score 0):

i think the json you are using is not proper have it check at jsonlint...for your consideration i am attaching the modified json in the answer

here is the modified json for full calander :-

```
[
    {
        "title": "AllDayEvent",
        "start": "2015-02-01"
    },
    {
        "title": "LongEvent",
        "start": "2015-02-07",
        "end": "2015-02-10"
    },
    {
        "id": "999",
        "title": "RepeatingEvent",
        "start": "2015-02-09T16: 00: 00"
    },
    {
        "id": "999",
        "title": "RepeatingEvent",
        "start": "2015-02-16T16: 00: 00"
    },
    {
        "title": "Conference",
        "start": "2015-02-11",
        "end": "2015-02-13"
    },
    {
        "title": "Meeting",
        "start": "2015-02-12T10: 30: 00",
        "end": "2015-02-12T12: 30: 00"
    },
    {
        "title": "Lunch",
        "start": "2015-02-12T12: 00: 00"
    },
    {
        "title": "Meeting",
        "start": "2015-02-12T14: 30: 00"
    },
    {
        "title": "HappyHour",
        "start": "2015-02-12T17: 30: 00"
    },
    {
        "title": "Dinner",
        "start": "2015-02-12T20: 00: 00"
    },
    {
        "title": "BirthdayParty",
        "start": "2015-02-13T07: 00: 00"
    },
    {
        "title": "ClickforGoogle",
        "url": "http: //google.com/",
        "start": "2015-02-28"
    }
]
```

check if it worked or not

Comment: tried to remove the events option and even emptied the array yet sadly still not showing.

Comment: thank you, it is fixed now, there some sort of hide and show stuff going on in my html.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error too- it was due to a CSS tag on the div element.

```
div{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

once I removed the inline-block everything appeared.

Answer (score 0):

Add this and this will work, It is a problem as due to new tab the display for calendar is none.

```
$('#Your Tab ID').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    $("#calendarID").fullCalendar('render');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys I'm having this same issue however when I click on any button the calendar will load. Ive tried everything above but could not get it. I took an option from @Wolfgang Leon and put this together for it to work. I added a countcheck for the calendar because I would be getting mutliple calendars when i switch tabs.

```
        render: function() { 

        let calCount = 0;

        $(function(){
            $('#YOUR CAL ID', this.el).fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay',
                    ignoreTimezone: false
                },
                defaultView: 'month',
                selectable: true,
                editable: true
            });
        });

        $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) { 
            var tab = e.currentTarget.hash
            if( tab == '#YOUR TAB ID' && calCount == 0){
                $('#YOUR CAL ID').fullCalendar('render')
            }
        });

    }
```

I put this inside of my render function after backbone is initialized. ( noob to backbone ). let me know if this helps or if theres a better way I can write this as I'm still learning.